# How to call javascript function in ClassLibrary project

Tags: javascript, c#-3.0

I have one ClassLibrary project in which I want to call a javascript `function` which should return some value.

How can I call a javascript `function` from my CS page in c#?

I search in google but not get perfect solution

Comment: Is this in the context of a .net application in .net 3.0, or is this in the context of I'm in a raw class library and want to interpret the JavaScript within this library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367946/calling-javascript-from-a-class-library

Answer (score 0):

> How can I call a javascript `function` from my CS page in c#?

A class-library is basically a DLL that mostly encapsulates code and you can reference to from other class-libraries(DLLs) and use - The client code in your case would probably be an ASP.NET application DLL, I assume.

You can always call a JavasScript `function` from a C# / Class-Library using the `RegisterStartupScript` method:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);
```

Just take on account that this code ***should*** be run in the context of a ASP.NET `Page` class in the event of the page is getting loaded (`Page_Load`).

In the case of a Class-Library, just make sure to have the right reference to it in your project (*Right-Click on your project → Select Add Reference → Select and add your class-library*).

Example code:

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String csname1 = "PopupScript";
    String csname2 = "ButtonClickScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();

    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
    {
      String cstext1 = "alert('Hello World');";
      cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Page reference to class Library and execute the JavaScript function inside the class library.

```
MyClassLib lib = new MyClassLib();
lib.RunJs(this.Page);

// In Class Lib 

Public Class MyClassLib 
{
  public void RunJs(System.Web.UI.Page page)
  {
      ClientScriptManager js = Page.ClientScript;
      ......
  }
}
```

I have not tried this please have a try on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can call JavaScript Function from code behind using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript.

like:

**JS Code:**

```
function TestFunction() { 
       Alert("Test Function!!") 
       }
```

**Code Behind:**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "TestFunction();", true);
```